# How to play audio via a specific sound card?

Tags: audio, vb6

I need to play a sound (.WAV file) from a Visual Basic 6 application.  However, the PC is equipped with multiple sound cards and the user should be able to use it.

Up till now a default sound card was supported and I would play a sound like this:

```
CommandString = "Open " & Chr$(34) & mstrFilename & Chr$(34) & " type waveaudio alias MediaFile"
mciSendString CommandString, vbNullString, 0, 0&

If PlayFromPercent <= 0 Then
    CommandString = "play MediaFile"
    lngRetcode = mciSendString(CommandString, vbNullString, 0, 0&)
Else
    CommandString = "play MediaFile from " & CLng(lngLength * (PlayFromPercent / 100))
    lngRetcode = mciSendString(CommandString, vbNullString, 0, 0&)
End If
```

Is there a way to adapt this code for a specific sound card or is there a different approach I could take (e.g. DirectX or a commercial 3rd Party Library)?

Bonus, if the approach supports playing the file from a specific position (as you can see, the code above supports it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work; call `mciSendCommand()` with `MCI_SET` & [`MCI_WAVE_SET_PARMS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) setting `wOutput` to the desired playback device's ID.

- You can get `IDDevice` for `mciSendCommand()` via `mciGetDeviceID("waveaudio")`
- Its not 100% clear what `wOutput` wants, its probably the same ID as returned by `waveOutGetDevCaps()`